# What are apple's app store guidelines for the big icon (512x512)

Tags: iphone, app-store

I want to distribute an iPhone app to the store and cannot find any guidelines for the iTunesArtwork icon. I heard it has to be jpg, but

- can it also be .png?
- do they add the rounded corners?
- do they add shine?
- ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information is all in the iTunes Connect part of the Apple website.  Look for the "Download the Developer Guide" PDF in:
https://itunesconnect.apple.com

You can put the same image into your Ad Hoc distribution (in the .ipa bundle) if you want it to appear in iTunes when doing Ad Hoc testing.

**Update:** removed old broken link, see comments for the new link.

Comment: Do you mean http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/145-Distributing_Applications/distributing_applications.html?

Comment: you can also check this article https://www.whatmattered.com/publishing-mobile-apps-on-app-store-google-play/

Answer (score 2):

They say the image has to be JPG or TIF, but they *sometimes* accept PNGs. You can try submitting it with a PNG, but I'm not sure it's worth the risk given how much time it takes for them to review submissions. If they do reject it for that reason alone, you'll just have to resubmit and keep waiting.

They'll add the rounded corners and highlights for you, though.

Answer (score 1):

PNG's work but make sure they are at least 24 bit as this caused me a lot of trouble.  Apple accepted the 8 bit file but it looked horrible scaled down.

Comment: The funny thing is, if you upload a PNG, they don't add rounded corners (or at least not at ALL occasions). I think their gfx script works differently (or not at all) with PNGs. Or maybe just some PNGs. I don't think it says anywhere if the file should be PNG, JPEG or anything else though.